# How to use generics in spring?

Tags: java, spring, generics

i have read lot of oline articles and couldnt find an answer and i have tried to make it correct and not able to do it.

Can anyone help,how to initialize generics in bean file and make it work?

**Config File**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
    <beans xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans"
        xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
        xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans.xsd">

        <bean id="collectionDemo" class="com.prashant.Collections6.CollectionDemo">
                <constructor-arg index="0" type="String" value="google"/>
                <constructor-arg index="1" type="String" value="gooogle"/>
        </bean>

    </beans>
```

**CollectionDemo.java**

```
public class CollectionDemo<T> {
    private T id,phoneNumber;

    public CollectionDemo(T id, T phoneNumber) {
        super();
        this.id = id;
        this.phoneNumber = phoneNumber;
    }

    public T getId() {
        return id;
    }

    public void setId(T id) {
        this.id = id;
    }

    public T getPhoneNumber() {
        return phoneNumber;
    }

    public void setPhoneNumber(T phoneNumber) {
        this.phoneNumber = phoneNumber;
    }

    @Override
    public String toString() {
        return "CollectionDemo [id=" + id + ", phoneNumber=" + phoneNumber
                + "]";
    }

}
```

**ColleactionApp.java**

```
package com.prashanth.Collections6;

import org.springframework.context.ApplicationContext;
import org.springframework.context.support.FileSystemXmlApplicationContext;

public class ColleactionApp {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        ApplicationContext app=new FileSystemXmlApplicationContext
        ("/src/main/java/com/prashanth/Collections6/beans.xml");
        CollectionDemo<String> coll=(CollectionDemo<String>) app.getBean("collectionDemo");
        System.out.println(coll);
    }
}
```

Comment: Can you explain what's wrong?

Comment: i just want to instantiate class using string type as we do in core java  and how do i achieve it using bean configuration file.

Comment: And what's wrong with your current solution?

Comment: ERROR:

Exception in thread "main" org.springframework.beans.factory.CannotLoadBeanClassException: Cannot find class [com.prashant.Collections6.CollectionDemo] for bean with name 'collectionDemo' defined in file [P:\YYYPPP\Dropbox\Spring Workspace\spring-tutorials\src\main\java\com\prashanth\Collections6\beans.xml]; nested exception is java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: com.prashant.Collections6.CollectionDemo..

Comment: For one, don't post stacktraces in comments. Edit your question. Two, how is that in the least bit related to generics? Search for `ClassNotFoundException`. You're missing a class from your classpath.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The issue you've posted in the comments is because of a typo

```
<bean id="collectionDemo" class="com.prashant.Collections6.CollectionDemo">
```

should be

```
<bean id="collectionDemo" class="com.prashanth.Collections6.CollectionDemo">
```

assuming

```
package com.prashanth.Collections6;
```

is the correct package name.

The "issue" with generics is

```
<constructor-arg index="0" type="String" value="google"/>
<constructor-arg index="1" type="String" value="gooogle"/>
```

Spring will use the `type` you specified to match constructor arguments. But your class constructor's arguments are not of type `String`, they are of type `T`, which erase to `Object`. Either change it to

```
<constructor-arg index="0" type="Object" value="google"/>
<constructor-arg index="1" type="Object" value="gooogle"/>
```

or remove the `type` altogether.

Generics are a compile time concept. They do not exist at runtime. But Spring uses reflection at **runtime** to generate beans. There's no type argument to specify for your generic types in the bean definitions.

Answer (score 1):

try this

```
<bean id="collectionDemo" class="test.CollectionDemo">
    <constructor-arg value="google" />
    <constructor-arg value="gooogle" />
</bean>
```

Comment: hi,

it doesn't work...where are we setting the value for type T?

Comment: @terminator You don't. Generics are a compile time concept.

Comment: @SotiriosDelimanolis, can you please give me an idea how to implement the above problem.

Comment: Your problem is not related to generics. The generic type T only exists for the compiler, to allow type-checking at compile-time, but it does not exist not in the VM. You can't get runtime errors for generic issues, and you can not specify the generic type when creating an object at runtime, because at runtime there are no generics.